# How to properly declare a list in a class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Context: I'm at the second year of Uni and we started using classes and understanding of creating some little applications. I'm building an employer class, every employer has 4 parameters: serial_number, name, surname, earnings and then there also junior and senior employers, with all the above but other parameters too. For example junior employers have a set of skills and intern: first one is a list of skills that a junior can have and the second is at which senior employer they are assigned.
ex. Junior with serial_number3 is the intern of Senior with serial_number1

NOW: I make use of the employer.h for the easy stuff, but when I get into declaring the list skills I just didn't understand what I should do.

```
#ifndef JUNIOR_H
#define JUNIOR_H

#include "employer.h"

#include <list>
using namespace std;

class junior : public employer
{
public:
    junior(string serial, string name, string surname, double earns, list<string> sk, string in)
        : employer(serial, name, surname, earns), skills(sk), intern(in) {}

    list<string> getSkills() const { return skills; }
    string getIntern() const { return intern; }

private:
    list<string> skills;
    string intern;

};

#endif // JUNIOR_H
```

if I try to write this in the main, it gives me now "no matching constructor for initialization of junior" and I have included the header

```
junior j("serial3", "name1" , "sur1", 3931, "cpp", "serial1");
```

Comment: `private: list<string> skills;` you already declared the member. What is missing from your code? What should it do that it isnt doing?

Comment: you also initialize the member already with a copy of the constructors parameter `skills(sk)`

Comment: and if you try `skills.push_back(sk);` you'd notice that `list<string>::push_back` cannot get a `list` passed.

Comment: if I had to guess, I would say it has something to do with code you do not show and `getSkills` returning a copy. Though, thats very far fetched. The code you posted looks ok as is

Comment: I wonder if I should do it differently in the body of the constructor,  is it going to take multiple skills parameters I pass through the main?

Comment: I believe you mean *employee*, which is pretty must the opposite of employer.

Comment: you should not do anything in the body of the constructor. The way to initialize the `skill` member is in the member initializer list just like you did it. The constructor takes only a single list as arguemtn, but that list can contain more than 1 string. Now I get the feeling that the problem is that you ponder about what could be wrong with code instead of just trying it, I might be wrong though

Comment: Offtopic: `using namespace std;` in a header BIG mistake, BIG problem.

Comment: is there code that does nto work as expected? or code that you do not know how to get working? Please show that code in case you didnt already

Comment: junior j("serial3", "name1" , "sur1", 3931, "cpp", "serial1");

Comment: if I try to write this in the main, it gives me now "no matching constructor for initialization of junior" and I have included the header

Comment: I should use std:: every time? is that a big problem?

Comment: `getSkills` should return a const reference, not a value. Otherwise this will copy your list every time it's called. Same with `getIntern`.

Comment: Do you want a single-element list containing `"cpp"`? If so, you want `{"cpp"}`.

Comment: *"I should use std:: every time? is that a big problem?"* Not a big problem for tiny practice programs, but will most likely be enforced on any real-life job you'll get.

Comment: If you want to know why `using namespace` is such an issue : [C++ Weekly - Ep 305 - Stop Using `using namespace`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZqjl9HEPZ8). Doing it in a header file is really asking for trouble. Writing correct code is more important then writing less code

Comment: _Do you want a single-element list containing "cpp"? If so, you want {"cpp"}_ thanks I had just to put {"cpp", "py"} or other skills in { ... }

Comment: You're welcome. Also note that `std::list` is very rarely used, due to performance problems. For general-purpose lists prefer `std::vector`.

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title or question. Press the checkmark next to one of the answers to mark it as solved. If there's no good answer, post your own and press the checkmark on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the constructor expects as the 5th parameter a `list<string>`. You are just handing in a normal `string` "cpp".

You can simply add a braced initializer list as the 5th parameter. In your case, just with one `string` only: "cpp". This will create a `list` with one member "cpp".

I also recommend qualifying your parameter as `const` reference. This will avoid a lot of copying.

Then your program looks like the following and will compile.

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

using namespace std;

struct employer {
    string serial{};
    string name{};
    string surname{};
    double earns{};
    employer(const string& serialp, const string& namep, const string& surnamep, const double earnsp) :
        serial(serialp), name(namep), surname(surnamep), earns(earnsp) {};
};

class junior : public employer
{
public:
    junior(const string& serial, const string& name, const string& surname, const double earns, const list<string>& sk, const string& in)
        : employer(serial, name, surname, earns), skills(sk), intern(in) {}

    list<string> getSkills() const { return skills; }
    string getIntern() const { return intern; }

private:
    list<string> skills;
    string intern;

};
int main() {
    junior j("serial3"s, "name1"s, "sur1"s, 3931, { "cpp"s }, "serial1"s);
}
```

Using `using namespace std;` for small demo projects is ok. Later you should definitely avoid that.

I used also `string_literals`. With that `"Hello World"s`will be of type `string`

Comment: Thank you very much, it was a very clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

simply write "junior("serial3", "name1" , "sur1", 3931, "cpp", "serial1");" not
"junior j("serial3", "name1" , "sur1", 3931, "cpp", "serial1");".......why are u writing j with it???

Comment: I used j to be able to write in my main things like this: 'cout << j.getName() << endl;' and I figured out by another user that my error was using "cpp" and not {"cpp"} -> junior j("serial3", "name1", "sur1", 3931, { "cpp" }, "serial1");